# Installing QGIS on Fedora?

Tags: qgis, installation, linux, fedora

Having problems installing QGIS 2.18 on Fedora 27. Used Copr repo but QGIS simply won't fire up when i try to launch it. Installation seems to go ok without any errors.

Anyone else having issues?

Comment: Can you link to the copr repo. And start it from the command line and post the output somewhere.

Comment: Any reason for using copr repo? Just installed QGIS from default fedora repo and worked fine for me.

Comment: Also tried from default repo - same result <- thats why I also deceided to try try copr.

Comment: After inspecting a bit it seems like Im missing some shared libraries -> qgis: error while loading shared libraries: libsz.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 4):

Found libsz.so.2 in a local library used by another software on my machine (FME Desktop). Copied this file to /usr/lib and ran ldconfig. This solved my issue this time....

Comment: You may try `apt-cache policy libsz2` (or the equivalent dnf or yum commands) to see what you have and what you can get. It is needed by libgdal20 via libhdf5.